# To judge whether a variable in the ejs

Tags: node.js, ejs

Here's my application:

**index.js**

```
function index(req, res) {
    res.render('admin/index');
}

module.exports = index;
```

**index.ejs**

```
<%
    if(data) {
%>
        <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">login fail</div>
<%
     }
%>
```

I got an error saying:

**data is not defined**

I want to check whether the variable exists, and to display the dialog if it does. What should I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Either rewrite the check as follows:

```
<% if (typeof data !== 'undefined') { %>
```

... or check the property on `locals` (local variables object) instead:

```
<% if (locals.data) { %>
```

Explanation: when EJS compiles a template into a function, it does not populate its variables' stack based on the `options` supplied. Instead, it wraps this function with `with` statement:

```
with (locals || {}) {
  (function() {
  // ... here goes the template content
  })();
}
```

Now, the data object (second parameter of `render`) is passed into the template function as `locals` variable, it's against this object all the checks are made. The point is, if accessed `somevar` is never defined in the local template scope (by `var` statement), and doesn't exist in `locals` object either, it'll cause a `ReferenceError: somevar is not defined` error.

*(one can disable with-wrapping, setting `_with` option of template to `false`, but by default it's just undefined)*